# What does 05 9,14 * * 1-5 mean in airflow?

Tags: cron, airflow, directed-acyclic-graphs

I am new to Airflow and was just wondering if anyone could help me decode this schedule_interval timing.

```
dag = DAG('mya-dag', default_args=default_args, schedule_interval='05 9,14 * * 1-5')
```

Does this mean my dag runs twice a day, every day, Monday-Friday, at 9:05 and 4:00PM?

Comment: https://crontab.guru/ is a great web app to help with that.

Comment: And no, it's 9.05 am and 2.05 pm.

Answer (score 0):

This is a cron expression which says "At 09:05 AM and 02:05 PM, Monday through Friday"

You can use a cron interpreter in the future for something like this (such as https://bradymholt.github.io/cron-expression-descriptor/)

I hope that helps!